# SharePoint 2013 Rest list insert, log when fails?

Tags: list, rest, log

Is it possible to log when a Restful insert into a list fails?

we have a web form that should be saving back to a list an I want to know when it is failing as well as succeeding.

Comment: Probably should have explained this more clearly. I don't have access to make any changes to the web form. and want to set something up on the list to monitor when it gets requests so I can spot requests that are failing because of type conversion errors or other errors. The only way I can think of to monitor rest request to the list is maybe IIS logs but I was hoping there was something in the list setting.

Answer (score -1):

Execute Query is the command which pushes data into the list. This has a Success Handler and Failure Handler.

You can write code in both these handlers and log as required.